# How to use ISBLANK to fill in data into cells which are empty?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to fill the empty cells with a word "REF" in excel column. I've been trying to use ISBLANK function for that but it gives me a SPILL error. Here's the formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I4:I21278)=FALSE,"REF")
```

Comment: A much easier way to do this is to put "REF" in a new cell, copy it, then select your column, then Go to > Special  > Blanks, and paste.

Comment: My data is too big, to go and copy to each cell.

Comment: @BigBen, just selecting empty values, type `REF` and press Ctrl+Enter =)

Comment: @Saad - that's why you use `Go To Special`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to go to Find and Replace, leave the find field blank and then just write in the replace field what ever text you want on the empty fields.